# How to autosize User control when it's shown

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, user-controls

I have a Winforms project with a bunch of User controls.  I'd like the user control to move itself to be at the 1,1 position relative to its container (whether it's a form or a Panel control).  And resize itself to be able to fit half the container.

What event can I respond to in the UserControl to be able to do this without any code having to be written in the container (e.g. the form or panel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the basic `Load` event.

The code could be like this:

```
private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control parent = this.Parent;
    if (parent != null)
    {
        this.Location = new Point(1, 1);
        this.Width = (parent.Width / 2);
        this.Height = (parent.Height / 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Paint event should work, unless I'm missing something.